# nested list into dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list

I have a nested list like this

```
lst = [[A,B], [C,D,E], [E,F,G,H]]
```

I want to convert it into the dataframe like below

| lst | key |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| F | 3 |
| G | 3 |
| H | 3 |

using pd.DataFrame(lst) would give each child list into rows not columns. Also, I would like to have an extra col to indicate which the number/order of the child list in the parent list. How could I approach this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) to demonstrate a pure pandas approach. Although it requires more resources than a list comprehension it's a good example of classical pandas functions:

```
df = (pd.Series(lst).explode()
        .rename_axis('key')
        .reset_index(name='lst')
        .eval('key=key+1') # optional
     )
```

*Note that python counts from `0` so you could leave the `eval('key=key+1')` out.*

Output:

```
   key lst
0    1   A
1    1   B
2    2   C
3    2   D
4    2   E
5    3   E
6    3   F
7    3   G
8    3   H
```

Comment: Alternative: `pd.Series(dict(enumerate(lst, 1)), name='lst').explode().rename_axis('key').reset_index()`

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension with `enumerate` for counter:

```
lst = [['A','B'], ['C','D','E'], ['E','F','G','H']]

df = pd.DataFrame([(y, i) for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1) for y in x], 
                  columns=['lst','key'])

print (df)
  lst  key
0   A    1
1   B    1
2   C    2
3   D    2
4   E    2
5   E    3
6   F    3
7   G    3
8   H    3
```

Simialar alternative with generator:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(((y, i) for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1) for y in x), 
                  columns=['lst','key'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode` to expand the list:

```
df = (pd.Series(lst).explode().to_frame('lst')
        .assign(key=lambda x: x.index+1).reset_index(drop=True))
print(df)

# Output
  lst  key
0   A    1
1   B    1
2   C    2
3   D    2
4   E    2
5   E    3
6   F    3
7   G    3
8   H    3
```